# Help with evaluating a line integral over a rectangle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Need help evaluating a line integral without using Green's Theorem over a rectangle where the boundary of the rectangle is [a,b] x [c,d]

My question formally is:

Evaluate the line integral directly, rather than use Green's Theorem, $\int_C x\ dy$ where $C$ is the boundary of the rectangle $[a,b] \times [c,d]$

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeK7R.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the line integral of $f$ along $C$ with respect to $y$ is given by $$\int_Cf(x,y)dy=\int_b^af\left(x(t),y(t)\right)\cdot y'(t)\space dt$$

where $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ parametrizes the boundary $C$. In your case, $f(x,y)=x$. Since $C$ is a the boundary of a rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, we shall split up $C$ into four line segments, namely $$C=C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4$$

Call $$v_1=(a,c)$$ $$v_2=(b,c)$$ $$v_3=(b,d)$$ $$v_4=(a,d)$$

These are the four corners of the rectangle. Then the line segments parametrizing each side of the boundary rectangle $C$ are: 
$$C_1(t)=(1-t)v_1+tv_2,\space \text{for}\space t\in[0,1]$$ $$C_2(t)=(1-t)v_2+tv_3,\space \text{for}\space t\in[0,1]$$ $$C_3(t)=(1-t)v_3+tv_4,\space \text{for}\space t\in[0,1]$$ $$C_4(t)=(1-t)v_4+tv_1,\space \text{for}\space t\in[0,1]$$

Then $$\int_Cx\space dy=\left(\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}+\int_{C_3}+\int_{C_4}\right)x\space dy$$